# linear algebra, identity-endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

I am attempting to understand one line of the following problem's solution  which is given in a textbook. I would appreciate any assistance.
The problem is:

> $V$ is vector space over field $F$. Given two transformations, $\alpha: V  \to V$ and $\beta: V  \to V$ where both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are projections, show that $\ker(\alpha) = \ker(\beta)$ if and only if $\alpha\circ\beta = \alpha$ and $\beta\circ\alpha = \beta$.

The solution given is:

line one: Since $\ker(\alpha) = \ker(\beta)$ then this implies that

line two: $\alpha(\sigma_1 - \beta) = 0$ and $\beta(\sigma_1 - \alpha) = 0$

line three: which implies that $\alpha\beta = \alpha$ and $\beta\alpha = \beta$.

In line two, $\sigma_1$ is the identity element for multiplication ($\operatorname{End}(V)$ is an associative unital $F$-algebra}.

I understand lines one and three but cannot reason why line two follows from (or is implied by) line one. And why is $\sigma_1$ used rather than, say $e$ or $1$?

Comment: Why $\sigma_1$ is used, is a mystery to me. But, it follows that if $x \in ker(\beta)$ we have that $\alpha(I-\beta)(x)=\alpha(x)=0$ because $x \in ker(\beta)=ker(\alpha)$. Can you see what happens if $x \not \in ker(\beta)$, taking into account that $\beta$ is a projection?

Comment: egreg:  Thank you for assistance. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing $\sigma_1$ is the identity element for *composition*, i.e., $\sigma_1(v) = v \forall v \in V$ and so

$$ (\alpha \circ (\sigma_1 - \beta)) (v) = \alpha(v - \beta(v)) $$

But $\beta(v-\beta(v)) =\beta(v) - \beta(v) = 0 \implies v - \beta(v) \in ker(\beta) \forall v \in V$ (this follows because $\beta$ is a projection) and since $ker(\alpha) = ker(\beta)$ then we can conclude $\alpha(v - \beta(v)) = (\alpha \circ (\sigma_1 - \beta)) (v) = 0 \forall v \in V$.

The other claim follows similarly.

Comment: cronos2: Thank you for assistance and for detailed exposition.